# Impedir DROP TABLE

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, sqlite3, permissões

Gostaria de impedir deleções em uma tabela no SQLite.

```
CREATE TRIGGER nao_deletar_tabela BEFORE DELETE ON tabela
  BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(IGNORE);
  END;
```

Funcionou! Sempre que é executado um `DELETE`, nada acontece.

O problema e a minha dificuldade é: Ainda assim é possível deletar os registros usando usando `DROP TABLE`.

Como eu posso impedir o comando `DROP TABLE`?

Comment: Acho que a melhor coisa a se fazer é não dar permissão de administrador pro usuário final. E proteger o código contra injeção de SQL na camada de aplicação e não no banco.

Comment: É um caso específico, onde estou reaproveitando o banco de uma aplicação já existente e de terceito, e essa, em algumas tarefas, executa uma 'limpeza'. Nas tarefas simples e limitadas ela executa um DELETE, o qual eu consegui bloquear. Quando executa uma limpeza completa ela faz um DROP e recria o banco. Preciso no banco impedir que essa aplicação, qual eu não tenho controle, não limpe esses dados usando o DROP.

Comment: Em MS SQL Server eu retiraria permissão de `DROP` do usuário que este aplicativo teimoso usa para se conectar ao banco. Neste caso, removeria a *role* **db_owner**. O sqlite tem este tipo de recurso?

Comment: Pois é, o sqlite não tem recurso de Permissão (GRANT) :(

Comment: @thiagobarradas o SQLite não é dos melhores bancos para se usar em produção pois não conta com autenticação. Para evitar esses problemas recomendo que crie alguma rotina na sua aplicação para sincronizar com outro banco de dados.

Comment: @gmsantos mas ele mencionou que é um codigo legado. =\

Comment: @heat não confundir código legado com reaproveitamento de um banco já existente.

Comment: sim sim sim. Foi mal se não percebi que ele esta criando uma nova aplicação aproveitando banco existente.

Comment: Tem um monte de conceito "perigoso" aqui nos comentários. Do mesmo jeito que dá pra dropar uma tabela no SQLite, dá pra deletar uma tabela até diretamente pelo filesystem em qq outro banco, se a base é local. O problema é usar a arquitetura certa no lugar certo. E o SQLite é usado com sucesso em produção em ima infinidade de coisas. Dificilmente alguém aqui usa um browser que não dependa de SQLite, ou um celular que não dependa de SQLite, e várias outras coisas. Como sempre, o segredo é usar chave pra parafuso, e martelo pra prego (o problema é se estiver acontecendo o inverso).

Comment: @thiagobarradas Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Basicamente não dá. Qualquer tentativa falhará.

Você não deu contexto ao que deseja fazer então pode ser que seu problema seja outro.

## Impedir o acesso ao arquivo

Se você quer impedir um usuário de causar problemas com os dados. Esquece. Ele poderá fazer o que quer de uma forma ou outra.

A única forma de não permitir que ele faça estrago é não deixar ele ter acesso ao arquivo onde está a base de dados e só sua aplicação acessar onde está o arquivo. Isto é virtualmente impossível em ambiantes que você não tenha tenha controle total o que é improvável que tenha.

## Impedir acesso ao SQL

Se sua aplicação está dando acesso SQL para o usuário e está com medo dele fazer algo errado, tire o acesso. Não importa se tem alguma utilidade dar este acesso, se tem que limitar desta forma, não pode dar acesso total. Você teria que fazer um interpretador que verificasse se pode fazer o comando ou não. É complicado.

Quando falo de usuário, é qualquer usuário, mesmo algum programador.

Note que não impede o acesso direto ao arquivo. Lembre-se que você está usando um banco de dados feito para [circunstâncias específicas](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) (eu até uso para outros casos mas sei o que estou fazendo). Mê acesso ao seu arquivo e eu faço o que eu quiser com os dados lá, até mesmo apagar os registros individualmente. Eu acabo com este `TRIGGER` que você criou em menos de um minuto.

Esta recomendação de impedir o uso direto do SQL só vale se o usuário/programador não tem acesso ao arquivo.

## Impedir falha de segurança

Se está preocupado com uma falha de segurança deixar deletar os dados, não perca tempo. Falhas de segurança podem trazer mais problemas que isto. E a solução é resolver as falhas de segurança. Não tem outro jeito.

## Impedir erros seus

Se está preocupado com isto, seria bom pensar em outro banco de dados. O SQLite é feito para aplicações relativamente simples (nem precisa ser tão simples assim) e programadores que que conseguem lidar com toda a base sem cometer erros catastróficos. Ele te dá velocidade, flexibilidade, liberdade e até confiabilidade, mas não dá segurança através de privilégios de acesso.

## Soluções alternativas

#### Ferramenta correta

Se tiver um motivo forte que exija a personalização de privilégios mesmo, então você terá que usar outro banco de dados. Um que forneça a possibilidade bem granular do que cada usuário pode fazer. Mas note que mesmo neste caso, se alguém tiver acesso ao processo deste banco de dados e acesso aos arquivos ele poderá com algum trabalho passar por cima deste tipo de restrição também.

#### Limitar o SQLite

Você pode modificar o código do SQLite para impedir o comando nesta ou em todas as condições. Precisará saber um pouco de C, estudar o código, tomar cuidado, mas é possível adaptar para o que você quer.

Não estou aconselhando fazer isto, apenas dando uma alternativa.

Novamente isto não resolve nada se houver acesso direto ao arquivo.

## Conclusão

Se você tem total controle sobre o banco de dados dificilmente esta proteção será necessária.

Se o usuário tem acesso ao arquivo, ele poderá fazer o que quiser por mais que você proteja desta forma.

Em tese existe uma forma de proteger mais que é criptografar todo o arquivo de forma que só sua aplicação possa acessá-lo. Mas mesmo que isto seja efetivo cai no primeiro caso, você irá se proteger de você mesmo. Não parece ser necessário já que ninguém comete um erro e dá um `DROP TABLE` sem querer.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -4):

Muitas vezes quem tem conhecimento avançado pensa que não precisa mais pesquisar!

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trg_notDropTable] ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @data XML;
    DECLARE @schema sysname;
    DECLARE @object sysname;
    DECLARE @eventType sysname;

    SET @data = EVENTDATA();
    SET @eventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'sysname');
    SET @schema = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]', 'sysname');
    SET @object = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'sysname') 

    if(@object = 'tblCliente')
    begin
        PRINT 'Esta tabela não pode ser removida! Tabela essencial para plano de negócios\n'
        rollback
    end

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
end
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER [Trg_notDropTable] ON DATABASE
```

Comment: Dá quase na mesma, se a pessoa consegue dropar a tabela ela deleta o trigger. Em se tratando de SQLite, o tratamento real do problema está sendo feito na camada errada. Aliás, eu já tinha tratado desta questão [em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38786/impedir-drop-table#comment85221_38786) - se a idéia é o usuário trabalhar diretamente no SQL, melhor usar um engine que permita permissões, ou abstrair a interface. O trigger acaba sendo um remendo em um problema maior.

Comment: Aliás, eu gostaria de ver esse seu código funcionando em uma base SQLite, teria como fazer um em http://sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: Oracle tem algo parecido , mas o cidadão tiver acesso dropa a trigger , em geral isto é política de acesso , tive um problema uma vez com um ERP de mercado por um bug deles o dicionário deles não batia com o do Oracle , o Oracle tinha coluna a mais , resultado ele DROPAVA AS COLUNAS , não sabíamos de onde vinha o comando cogitei criar uma trigger assim mas conseguimos corrigir , a ideia da trigger de evento no Banco faz sentido mas controle de acesso é tudo. SQLlite como o nome sugere é algo limitado por ser leve , seria como reclamar que o carro popular é pequeno...